# Build off of default UITableViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I'm trying to build a custom `UITableViewCell` where the custom title label is correctly aligned with a default `UITableViewCell`'s title label. However, the labels are not correctly aligned as shown below. The custom cell was made in a xib file.

[image: The Username label is not aligned with the below cells, which are default <code>UITableViewCell</code>s]

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: Rather than creating cell that matches default cell, I'd suggest having two custom cells, one for each layout that you need. You theoretically could adjust your cell to match the default one, but you have no assurances that later iOS version might tweak the standard cell on you. Don't try to match it, but always use custom cells. That way you'll know that it always matches.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could increase the left margin of your label (Username) so that it will be aligned with others' labels.

Comment: problem is it changes due to autolayout, but Rob's answer works